# Suggested edit summary cut off

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, design, edit-summary

Just noticed [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7654978). On my machine (OS X 10.10.3, Chrome 41.0.2272.118 ), the summary is cut off:

[image]

Can anyone else repro? I'm half suspecting this is a Chrome bug, just because it seems really weird, but I've been wrong in the past.

Comment: For what it's worth I can't repro on Linux / Firefox, it [looks good to me](https://i.imgur.com/EvU9MH3.jpg) here.

Comment: You are correct on OS X 10.10, I am also using Chrome -- Version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit) and seeing that. It seems like just half the letter 'e' for me as well though, I see it continue to the next line with what look like the rest of the words in the 'sentence': SOME... OTHER TECHNIQUES -- so maybe just a rendering issue with a single character going over the 'overflow' boundary before sentence wrapping on mine.

Comment: Repro'd on OS X 10.10 with Safari.

Comment: I just tested it in Firefox 37.01 and getting the same cut-off on the letter 'e' -- I am thinking it is an OS X 10.10 quirk. I would be curious to see if other people (with different OS X versions) have the same issue. I am using 10.10.2

Comment: Pale Moon (a Gecko-based browser) 25.3.1 on Win 8.1 x86 shows no glitching.

Comment: No repro on Chrome & Firefox (latest) on Linux.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 41.0.2272.118 , Windows

Comment: Another pluralization bug: Click "(more)" under the users who approved the edit and see "*Kerrek SB has approved 1257 edit suggestions and rejected **1 edit suggestions***". I hope I don't get stabbed with a giant '*S*' now....

Comment: Repro'd on Win 7 SP1 Chrome 41.0.2272.118

Comment: No repro on Win 7 SP1 IE 11

Comment: No repro on Win 7 SP1 Firefox 34.0.5

Comment: No repro on Win 7 SP1 Firefox 37.0.1

Comment: Most certainly Chrome...

Comment: @RaeenHashemi, Chrome on Linux is fine for me..

Comment: No repro Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit), Linux 3.19.2-1-ARCH

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 m (64-bit), Windows 8.1.  If I reduce the ZOOM to 90% the problem goes away.

Comment: @VincentUgenti I'm on Win 7 Chrome, and reducing the zoom enhances the issue, but increasing to over 100% solves it. Strange